# Why can not write some characters on pop up in a website by my mobile with android?

Tags: android

When I am in a website on my mobile, my device does not allow put some letters in a pop up that showed at the begining, why happened on my mobile Virgin (kyocera)?.. Who can I help me about that question? in another devices work very well

Answer (score 0):

Open your browser then press the `Menu button -> More -> Check if "Text encoding" is "Unicode UTF-8"`. If not change it.